# prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) missing in swift 3.0/Xcode 8 b6

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue, beta

Using xcode 8 beta 6.

Type override func prepare and I see this ..

[image]

But I am looking for

[image]

prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)

Is this a bug? This class is a subclass of ViewController?

Comment: Why are you still using Xcode beta? The final version is out. You need to update.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe this was a bug in Beta 6. I'm using the GM seed, and it is working:

[image: prepareforsegue]

BTW: In beta 6, the method was renamed to

```
prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
```